# Having difficulty understanding bootstrap scroll spy

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having difficulty understanding how scrollspy works. 
I have looked at many examples and am still confused, which is why I am here. I understand that it watches for scrolling and when it hits a certain id it does something. In the case of the code below it highlights a certain link on the nav bar. My question is where is the code making the changes? I don't see any HTML or CSS that is changing the color of the links on the nav bar. Say I wanted to change the color of the link text to blue when that section of the page is scrolled to, what would I change? The code below is from the w3 school's section on bootstrap which I've been playing around with. Sorry if this is not formatted correctly and thank you in advance for your responses.
 https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
      body {
          position: relative; 
      }
      #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
      #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
      #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
      #section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
      #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
      </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

<div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is looking for scroll page event in javascript. When you scroll to element with '#myId'. Bootstrap will add class active to li element in navbar, which has a child element linking to '#myId'.

When you scroll to element with id 'section1' the navbar code would look like this:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```